# Previous post in WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have loop which displays a list of posts, the posts are displayed with sorting

```
 $query = new WP_Query([
                'posts_per_page' => 3,
                'post_type' => 'agency',
                'meta_query' => array(

                    array(
                        'key'     => 'date', 
                        'value'   => array( 0, 999 ), 
                        'compare' => 'BETWEEN', 
                        'type'    => 'NUMERIC', 
                    ),
                ),
                'meta_key' => 'date', 
                'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num', 
                'order'    => 'ASC' 
            ]);
```

I need to get the metadata of the previous post from the loop, I tried to do it like this

```
get_post_meta(get_previous_post()->ID, 'date', true);
```

But I am getting the previous post wrong, ignoring the arguments in WP_Query

Comment: Is `echo get_previous_post()->ID;` print correct id?

Comment: Does this help? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/280965

Comment: @NoNAME get wrong ID

Comment: @CBroe check if($prevPost) get false (

Comment: I don’t think these functions are supposed to work with custom queries in the first place - they refer to the _main_ query. Someone has written a function here that is supposed to help get this info for custom queries, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56677419/1427878 - but they warn that it can get quite resource hungry, for lots of posts. If you don’t want to risk that, then the proper way to solve this here, would probably be not to write your own custom query to begin with, but manipulate the WP main query to show only the posts you want, in whatever the current context is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, create into the loop have_posts

```
foreach($query->posts as $key => $value) {
                        if($value->ID == $post->ID){
                            $nextID = $query->posts[$key + 1]->ID;
                            $prevID = $query->posts[$key - 1]->ID;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
```

And now i can get prev and next post data. Just use

```
<?php echo get_the_title($nextID);?>
```